# Pinterest multiple parameters for detail url in description

Tags: pinterest

I am integrating the Pin it functionality in my website, but I am unable to pass multiple parameters in url or description . I have tried with the following code

```
    $detail_wow_pin = $baseurl.'/wow/Wowitems/wowdetail?
obj_id='.$obj_id.'&amp;obj_type='.$obj_type;

        <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?
url=http://softprodigy.in/thinkbright/wow/Wowitems&media=<?=$wowimg?>
&description=<?='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].''.$detail_wow_pin?>" 
count-layout="none">
    <img src="<?php echo IMG_WOWS; ?>/img/pinterest.png" alt="">
    </a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I find properly url encoding the entire href, confirming the ampersand (&) encodes as & inside the href attribute. Furthermore, & encodes as %26 inside the url parameter and moving the url parameter to the last place in the href attribute will properly create the link back to the page containing the image when clicked on from your pin it board.

Example:

```
<a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?media=http%3a%2f%2example.com%2fImages%2fimage.jpg&amp;description=Example+description.&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2FExample%2FExample.php%3Fparam1%3Dvalue1%26param2%3Dvalue2%26param3%3Dvalue3"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic Link for Pinterest**

> Below code will generate dynamic pinterest button for different pages.

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.example.com/page-one&amp;media=http://www.example.com/image/cache/data/image.jpg&amp;description=description will come here" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">
 <img src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" data-cfsrc="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" border="0">
</a>
```

Comment: How to add multiple media images in parameter?